# How to call a .SO function in C++ class in Android NDK

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

How to call a function from C class & the class is in prebuild .so file into C class in new project. For example i have a project-1 which 
create a prebuild .so file. Now in this project i have a C class named as "androidNdk".
In this class i have only one function that return a integer value.

```
int myFunction()
{
    int number = 10;
    return number;
}
```

I create a new project and load this .so file and call a myfunction() in C class. like this
This is new class named as "newAndroidNdk".

```
void newFunction()
{
    int str = myFunction();

    printf("%s", str);  
}
```

The problem is when i compile this project using ndk-build command it will give me this error 
"undefined reference to myfunction".

This is Android.mk in jni -> lib folder

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libndkfunction-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libndkfunction.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This is new project Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkfun
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndkfun.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libndkfunction-prebuilt        
 LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/jni/include                
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRAR
```

help me to solve this problem

Comment: you can create new method in a header file which is .h file. And import .h file into C class then call the new method from your C class.

Comment: There are no classes in C. What do you mean by that word?

Comment: Call that method from C file method which is in .c file.

Comment: This is the project -2 header file named as "newAndroidNdk.h "               void newFunction();